# The value of TIME(2) column is shown with extra precision zeros while the query returns only 2

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, time, dataset

I am running a simple sql query using the following code. In my query there is a column called *duration* with type `TIME(2)`. When I run the query normally on my *MySQL Workbench* the value of *duration* is correctly shown with only 2 precision points. But when I fill my `DataSet` using a `SqlDataAdapter` like the following this value is shown with 6 extra zeros on my `DataGridView`:

```
using (IDbConnection conn = dataFactory.GetDbConnection())
{
    conn.ConnectionString = Common.Conf.ConnectionString;
    MySqlDataAdapter daRunHistory = new MySqlDataAdapter();
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Name,Duration FROM MyTable;";
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    dsRunHistory = new DataSet();
    daRunHistory.SelectCommand = cmd;
    conn.Open();
    daRunHistory.Fill(dsRunHistory);
    conn.Close();
}
```

And it is not just the `DataGridView`, the zeros are in my `DataSet` as well.

Comment: Sounds like it's just a formatting issue. Have you ever try to format that `Duration` column in your datagridview? From [doc of TIME type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/time.html); _Some of these formats can include a trailing fractional seconds part in up to microseconds (6 digits) precision. Although this fractional part is recognized, it is discarded from values stored into TIME columns. For information about fractional seconds support in MySQL_, see Section [11.3.6, “Fractional Seconds in Time Values”](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fractional-seconds.html)

Comment: @SonerGönül Correct. So I just formatted my TIME in my selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up changing my query as follows to format my time:

```
SELECT Name, TIME_FORMAT(Duration, '%H:%i:%s') AS 'Duration' 
FROM MyTable
```